# Navigation failed because page crashed! JavaScript Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to go to a secondary URL after an action is completed on the first page on playwright, everytime I go to the secondary page the error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.goto: Navigation failed because page crashed
> =========================== logs ===========================
> navigating to "https://google.com", waiting until "load"
> ============================================================

my code is

```
await page.goto('https://youtube.com');
await sleep(10000);
await page.goto('https://google.com');
console.log("Passed this!");
```

Answer (score 3):

The "Navigation failed because page crashed" error can also be produced if the system Playwright is running on runs out of available RAM.

Comment: I think so as well

Comment: thanks you for the suggestion. But how do you solve this ? How do you increase the memory on chrome ?

Comment: @Axel if you are running PlayWright in a virtual machine, you can increase the RAM settings. If you are running PlayWright on a real system, maybe switch to a more powerful system. Sorry.

Comment: 
 I ve bypassed this issue, opening a new tab in chrome...it seems to clean some space.

Answer (score 0):

its just the page timeout. Just do await page.setDefaultTimeout(55555) or something

Comment: I don't think so, because there is a timeout exception for that